# Constructing a reverse order list of Ints in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I understand that I can define an ordered list of integers by use of the construct [1..10]. For example:

```
> [1..10] == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].
```

But if I want to define a similar list in reverse order, why does the following

```
> [10,9..1] == [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

work as expected but

```
> [10..1] == []
```

produces the empty list?

Comment: @Zeta Thanks for the reference. I guessed it must have already been asked previously but hadn't though of searching on 'decrement'

Comment: Actually, another user found that question (and answer), but their comment got automatically removed. They should get the honors, but I cannot recall the user name, sorry :/